# li:before not showing in IE8

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

I am having a problem with a list menu on on of our new websites.

I am using li:before to display a | before all the items in the menu. Using the following css:

```
#menu li:first-child:before {
    content:"";
    }

#menu li:before {
content: " | ";
}
```

For some odd reason this is working fine on a website i've done a while back: http://www.oneillsbedandbreakfast.com but it is not working on a site I am working on at the moment: http://www.scoridcottage.com/newdesign

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle? Does it work in Fx, Chrome and IE9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared for `:before` to work in IE8.
The same goes with the other pseudo-elements (like `:first-child`).

On `<!DOCTYPE>`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything working now!

That was some messy coding from my side...

Answer (score 5):

For `:before` to work in Internet Explorer 8, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be set. In your website, a comment appears before the doctype. This results in strange behaviors in some browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything working now!

That was some messy coding from my side...